# Look Me Up By Email problem

Tags: macos, icloud, catalina, system-settings, look-up

Does anybody have anything in the "Look Me Up By Email" tab? I'm trying to understand how to remove an item from "Look Me Up By Email". This app was **uninstalled** a long time ago and it's still showing on my Mac.

I also did a clean install of macOS Catalina. I don't know what more I can do. It's a bug or maybe I have a virus on my Mac (MacBook Air early 2015, macOS Catalina 10.15.1)?

[image]

I received a letter from MarginNote, but there's nothing useful here!

> This is just a residue in the look-me-up list.The app does not have
> access to refreshing the list when it is uninstalled on your devices.
> **We do have forwarded this issue to Apple’s dev team about this issue
> and hopefully, it could be fixed eventually.** A couple of words about
> this if what you are actually concerned about is your privacy
> protection. The feature is added in MarginNote 2 given that app
> supports sharing an exported notebook to a fellow MarginNote user so
> that some sort of teamwork can be achieved. It serves only this
> purpose and no more than that. Plus, ticking it off in the list is
> already an effective measure to turn it off for good. To sum up, it is
> a left-over option that can be turned off and will not affect your
> (un)using of your macOS device.
>
> Regards, MarginNote Support Team

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you had the application and then uninstalled it, you should be able to remove it.  Why do you think this is either a bug or virus on your Mac?

Comment: Well, I just don't know how to remove it. I have no idea what can I do about it now.

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.1.

Comment: @ReplicaFoxtrot I am on Mojave so as of now I don't know where to find that setting, but could you use any app like "easyfind" to search for strings like "remoteservice" or "com.apple.preferences.icloud" etc ? I found two files for the former and need to see what do they do.

Comment: All right, I'll try it.

Comment: As the letter says, see if you can refresh the list *after* installing the app too.

Comment: So what should I do? Should I install the app again and then fix this issue somehow?

Comment: Worth a try I'd say

Answer (score 2):

The GUI is located in the Apple ID > iCloud >  Options -> Look Me Up By Email window.

Mine is blank:

[image]

So why is mine blank and your filled? Because Apps that use iCloud can offer this service to other iCloud users so that they can find you.

As discussed [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7055930) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8389290) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250581915) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6543572), one way to remove the app is to delete it.  It may be that some apps give you the ability to turn it on or off, but it's really an app thing.

EDIT:

If the MarginNote application is not installed and you are still seeing this GUI, try this:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Type: `find $HOME -name '*MarginNote*' -ls`
3. Post the output.

If that doesn't work, then try this:

1. Install on a new machine (or in a VM), just so we know everything is clean.
2. Log in **but do not add your Apple ID**.  You should not see anything in the "look me up by email" GUI.
3. Log into iCloud but disable every service. If you see things in the GUI, then it's somewhere in your iCloud count that you can't reach.
4. Sync just the iCloud drive. If it appears, then there is a file in your iCloud drive that has this information. Go into Terminal and list all of the files with the "find $HOME -name '*MarginNote*'

Comment: If I delete my Apple ID and create a new one, then the window "Look Me Up By Email" will be blank as yours? What do you think?

Comment: I think that you need to delete the application on your MacBook. You could try bringing up a new Mac in a VM with no applications installed and see what happens.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have any apps on my mac now, and I reinstalled macOS several times, but the issue was always there.

Comment: You don't have MarginNoteXE installed anymore on your Mac?

Comment: That's the point! Exactly.

Comment: Okay @ReplicaFoxtrot, I gave you more things to try.

Comment: Delete the files from the command line! Or even using the find command. Try `find $HOME -name '*MarginNote*' -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Oh, be sure that you give Terminal complete file access

Comment: Try `sudo rm -rf /Users/[your username]/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~QReader~MarginNote` to kill the entire directory. Remember to include the backslash before the space between "Mobile" and "Documents" to escape the space in the file name.

Comment: Have you tried Apple Support?

Comment: No, but one person who has the same problem already did it and they couldn’t help him. So thanks for the idea, but it’s pointless.

Comment: Well, the data is somewhere in your iCloud account. I do not know if there is data in the iCloud account that is not accessible from the iCloudDrive. There was at some point, but this may not be the case anymore. That's really all I can say.

Answer (score 0):

Here's just an idea (I don't have this problem so I can't exactly test it out for myself). Open terminal, and simply type `defaults read | grep -aiC32 MarginNote`. The `defaults read` part lists out all of the preferences stored across any applications/plist files on your computer. If you find something in there, you'll need to figure out how to use `defaults` in order to edit it (that depends on what exactly it is that you find - though if you find something and have no clue how to proceed then just reply with your results and I can help you out). This may very well be inaccessible in iCloud, but if there's anywhere you can find it which maybe just might be editable, it would be in the plist files `defaults` helps you access.